# user comments in announcements

Tags: social, community

I want to enable user comments for announcements. What is the best way to do it?

I have used `microsoft.sharepoint.portal.socialcommentwebpart` for comments on pages. But is there a possibility to use it for individual announcements? Or is there another (maybe some built-in) way to have community comments on announcements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is Tags and Notes support in 2010 std/ent (based on Managed Metadata Service): http://mscerts.programming4.us/sharepoint/sharepoint%202010%20%20%20viewadd%20notes%20to%20a%20document%20or%20list%20item.aspx

Comment: Ivan's answer is better than mine...totally forgot about the Tags & Notes feature :)

Comment: great, but how to show the notes next to the related annoucment ? in all tiem view?

Answer (score 0):

The only clean OOB way I can think of doing this is to use a Multiline Text box field with **Append Changes to Existing Text** turn on (...note you need versioning turned on for the list to use this).  So each inidiviual entry for that field would be versioned along with who added it and when.  Kind of a poor man's commenting system for a individual list item.

A more advanced solution would be to build a custom SPField to do this, but that would be quite involved.